# Is it possible to have versions of a document (other than the current) automatically transfered to another document library?

Tags: document-library, versioning

I have a slide library that has major and minor versions enabled. Once a slide is updated to it's current version, I want the "new" old version to transfer to another document library. Is this possible? If so, how would I do it?

Comment: using OOTB functionality you can able to see version history of document and restore it as per requirement.

If you need to move old document before updating you need to do custom screen for upload document maybe it is not feasible using OOTB functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might be possible using a custom workflow, though it sounds fiddly.

Why not just switch off versioning and make users append a date to the file they upload instead?  Each file is then a stand-alone file.  Then you could create a workflow to copy the old file to the other document library.

You would just need to come up with a system so Sharepoint knows which file is the old file it needs to move.  You could have a tag for the document type e.g. Project Finance and another field with a unique number '1 to infinity' (you could use the ID field that the List comes with).  Get the workflow to check against the Project Finance tag, if there are two documents, the workflow checks the Created Date and moves the oldest one to a new location.